# Add eventListener to only one html page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have several html pages and I want to add an eventListener to only one html page.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){    
// along the scroll, the img's opacity changes.
});
```

In that html page, if I scroll the page, the full page img's opcacity changes.

The problem is that this listener triggers in other pages too,

How can I add this listener to one page only?

Comment: if you have this code in header, move it to that page only.

Comment: You can add that function to a `<script></script>` tag in your only html page you want it to load, and not put it into a js file that's imported in every page you have.

Comment: Lixus is correct, another option would be to add a class to the parent element and only trigger if it exsits?

Comment: Only add it to the one page? What prevents you have just adding it directly to the one page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `window.location` and then attach the event handler,

```
if(window.location.href === 'YOUR_URL') {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){    
    //your code
  });
}
```

Or you can append some `id` on `body` and check for its existence.

```
<body id="animate-stuff">

if(document.getElementById('animate-stuff')) {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', function(e){    
    //exec your code here
  });
}
```

Comment: Seems like a bad idea to have that check inside, would make more sense to wrap it in the if and not apply the event listener.

Comment: @epascarello oops, I meant that, just copypasted his code. Thanks, will change

Comment: does this remove the event when the page changes ?